# Using SelectedValue to Designate where the Parameter Value Should Aggregate

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, selectedvalue

I have a set of data that has several categories with totals for them. I am attempting to add a parameter in that allows me to assign the parameter amount to the designated category chosen.

See the below data:

Category:
Maintenance - $5000.00
Overhead - $6000.00
Gas & Oil - $2500.00

Parameter:
1-10000 (Depends on what you choose)

I am having trouble coming up with a measure that will designate the parameter amount to the selected Category. My idea was to use SelectedValue, but I continue to get errors.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.